# How to manage FCM push tokens

Tags: react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I would like to find a sustainable solution for storing FCM tokens used for push notifications. I am using React Native with Firebase.

The requirements are:

1. User-based application
2. Multiple devices per user supported
3. No stale tokens stored at any time.

My current approach is:

Maintain a table `user_devices` with columns:

- user_id,
- device_uuid
- fcm_token

Maintain a uniqueness constraint on fcm_token and device_uuid.

Upon key events, including but not limited to:

- application startup
- sign in
- onTokenRefresh

send the following to the backend:

- [device unique id](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-info#getuniqueid)
- FCM registration token
- user id, if there is one (done through authentication token)

The backend then upserts a row with the above values. If the device uuid exists, that means, we overwrite the token (and, potentially, the user_id) for that device uuid.

The above approach is flawed because:

- [device unique id](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-info#getuniqueid) can change at any point (device reset, update, app reinstall, etc...)
- registration token can change at any point

In other words, the table ends up storing many stale tokens and the application backend sends notifications to those stale tokens.

Additionally, the "Devices" frontend page (which shows the user their registered devices and reads from the above table) shows many duplicate devices that, really, represent the same device but have different device uuids.

One mitigation step could be to periodically send notifications to all tokens stored in the table with `dry_run=true`. Then, remove rows with tokens for which an error occurred. This is bad because it implies there is a period during which tokens are stale in the table.

I have scanned multiple resources online, including FCM documentation, but there is no mention on storing and maintaining those tokens in a real-world application. Are there any suggested approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiomatic approach is to remove a token when the Firebase Cloud Messaging API to send messages tells you that it is not valid.

For an example of how to do this, you can have a look at the Cloud Functions sample of [sending notifications](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js#L90-L108), which does the following:

```
  const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
  // For each message check if there was an error.
  const tokensToRemove = [];
  response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
    const error = result.error;
    if (error) {
      functions.logger.error(
        'Failure sending notification to',
        tokens[index],
        error
      );
      // Cleanup the tokens who are not registered anymore.
      if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
          error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
        tokensToRemove.push(tokensSnapshot.ref.child(tokens[index]).remove());
      }
    }
  });
  return Promise.all(tokensToRemove);
```

So each time you send one of more messages through FCM, you cull the invalid/outdated tokens from the database.

Comment: Thanks. This seems like a passive variation of the aforementioned imperfect solution (periodically check the validity of stored tokens). An implication is that the table can store a large number of stale tokens and we perform unwanted broadcast calls.

Comment: There are applications, such as PagerDuty, which achieve this - they provide a user-facing page that lists a user's devices and no duplicate ever appears. I wonder what kind of techniques they use? Additionally, string matching the return error messages seems very much not sustainable. It really surprises me this is the idiomatic approach.

Comment: The code removes the tokens as soon as they're used once. Within the FCM API this is the best I know of. I you find a better method, please share it as a self-answer.

Comment: I could not think of any solutions that would not involve changes on the FCM side, hence the question :). I believe a potential solution would have been to have `onRefreshToken` pass in the previous registration token (or a chain of previous tokens), but my guess is this would undermine some of the reasons those tokens are rotated in the first place. It is likely that most real-world applications do not face this issue by slashing one of the three requirements mentioned above. The other production-grade applications likely use a set of heuristics.