# FCM web - detecting and managing invalid tokens

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

1. Detecting invalid tokens

This SO answer [How to manage FCM push tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67562999/how-to-manage-fcm-push-tokens)) gives an example of how to detect invalid token. However this requires trying to send a message to it. In my app I never send messages directly to individual tokens, only to topics, and I dont want to risk sending test messages to real tokens and bothering my users. Is there a way around this? Testing a token without sending the actual message?

As documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.messaging.messaging.md#messaging_class), most of the send methods have a `dryRun` field that will "send the message in the dry-run (validation only) mode.", but in my experience it will still succeed even for invalid tokens

2. Unsubscribe to topics

In this section [Unsubscribe stale tokens from topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-tokens#unsubscribe_stale_tokens_from_topics) it is mentioned that stale tokens should be unsubscribed from any topic. I am not currently tracking what topics a given token is subscribed to, so is this really necessary? if yes is there an "unsubscribe all" way of doing it without targetting every single topic